# How to decode wordpress transient cache stored in database?

Tags: cache, transient

Wordpress stores caches using Transient and saved in `wp_options` table.

I can't read those stored values - a sample snapshot is as below.

If you know how to decode/read/parse them, please share.

[image]

Comment: try unserializing it.

Comment: By PHP? I would love to read right in MySQL if possible.

Comment: try this `get_site_transient('update plugins')`

Comment: I'm newbie to Wordpress, please guide more details on how to run your PHP call. Thank you ^^

Comment: run it like you run any other php code. It returns a value. `var_dump(get_site_transient('update plugins'));`. If you want to hook it somewhere then there's another process.

Comment: I may need your `include XXX` lines so that the PHP code can run @Karun

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25591/discussion-between-karun-and-nam-g-vu).